# Starlink No connection behind router EXCEPT when setting up ipv4 protocol custom DNS

Tags: networking, router, dns, ipv4

When connecting straight to the starlink connection everything works fine and I have internet connection.

However, when I place another router *(tp-link ER605)* after the starlink router I do not have internet access **except** when I set a custom dns *(8.8.8.8)* in the ipv4 config in windows.

The same router **works fine** without setting up dns **with another internet provider**.

Any ideas?

FYI: the adapters ipconfig /all output:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 4C-CC-6A-84-92-75
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5479:b2d8:b396:5ee1%7(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.161(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 26 October 2021 09:52:40
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, 2 December 2157 16:30:20
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 122473578
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-27-42-FD-EE-4C-CC-6A-84-92-75
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

**Edit, router config:**
[image: Connection to modem]
[image: DHCP settings]

Comment: It would be more interesting to see the connection status _of the router_ (IP address, DNS servers, etc.) – if your computer's "DNS servers" are pointing at the router, then the router's settings are possibly the problem.

Comment: @user1686 I've added the status of the router and DHCP settings. When I plug in a different ISP then I'm able to connect to the internet. No specific settings have been set for the other ISP, this is a new router to do load balancing (or rather failover) between the two ISP's.

Comment: I've never used Starlink, but it almost seems that they are not specifying the DNS servers in the DHCP options file, in which case you would want to manually add them to the profile.

Comment: @davidgo, I've tested another router (fritz 7590) and there it's working fine. So the issue is probably going to be somewhere in the tp-link ER605 I'm afraid